# Yii2 - Kartik Widget-Rating overwrite values

Tags: php, yii2, rating, kartik-v

it's possible overwrite the values of each star?
i need define step = 3.75, min = 0 and max = 15, and prevent from selecting half a star.
the values I want are:

> star 1 => 0; star 2 => 3.75; star 3 =>  7.5; star 4 => 11,25; star 5
>   => 15.

**form.php**

```
echo $form->field($model, 'rating')->widget(StarRating::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'stars' => 5, 
    'step' => 3.75,
    'min' => 0,
    'max' => 15,
    ]
]);
```

but when i make this, the selection of each star not display correctly, half of star is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you only want to display the client side (with manual numbers). And you will not get numbers from DB

the correct way is to overwrite the `star-rating` file. Which should be referred to the Kartik forum.

You must overwrite that the first star has a zero score (highlight first star = 0)

 However, you can use the following code in your **model**.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    // if ($insert) {  // only for Save (No Update)
        if (!empty($this->Your_field)) {
            $this->setAttribute('Your_field', $this->Your_field-3.75);
        }
    // }
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Instead of `your_field`, enter your field name (field of the rate).

Comment: I'm glad you were successful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the settings incorrectly.

Refer the [plugin documentation](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating) and demos for details.

**quotation krajee:**

> The logic for highlighting stars depends on the stars, min, max, and
>   step configurations. The percentage of each star to be highlighted for
>   each step, will be evaluated using the following expression:
>
> `STAR_HIGHLIGHT_PERCENT = (max - min) * step * 100 / stars`
>
> For example:
>
> If min = 0, max = 5, step = 0.5, and stars = 5, then
>   STAR_HIGHLIGHT_PERCENT will evaluate to 50% of each star for each
>   step.
>
> If min = 1, max = 5, step = 0.5, and stars = 5, then
>   STAR_HIGHLIGHT_PERCENT will evaluate to 40% of each star for each
>   step.
>
> **So, for example 2 above, the stars will not be completely highlighted
>   as desired. It is therefore important you set the configuration of
>   stars, min, max, and step correctly.**
>   Refer the [plugin documentation](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating) and demos for details.

#### for You:

```
'stars' => 4, 
'step' => 3.75,
'min' => 0,
'max' => 15,
```

**or**

```
echo StarRating::widget(['name' => 'rating', 
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'stars' => 5, 
    'step' => 3.75,
    'min' => 0,
    'max' => 18.75,
    'starCaptions' => new JsExpression("function(val){return val-3.75 + ' hearts';}")
    ]
]);
```

- **1** 

  If your field values are integers 1 to 5

  To display half stars and full stars, You must use round numbers.

After putting the numbers in the following formula:

```
(max - min) * step * 100 / stars
```

Equal to: `50% or 100%`

And to display only a full star, Equal to: `100%`

- **2**

  However, it is better that the `rate` and `step` are equal. 

  For example, if `step` is `2`, is better than `max` equal to 10 (5 Stars)
- **3**

  All of this varies according to the value of your **field**:
  for example:

  values: .5, 1, 1.5 , ... 5
  Default (stars=5,max=5,step=0.5)

  values: 1, 2, 3 , ... 5
  (stars=5,max=5,step=1)

  values: 1, 2, 3 , ... 12
  (stars=6,max=12,step=1) => Half star = one point

  values: 2, 4, 6 , ... 12
  (stars=6,max=12,step=1) => one star = 2 point

Comment: if i define `'min' => 0,
            'max' => 15,
            'step' => 3.75,
            'stars' => 4,` it's ok but i need **5 stars** when star 1 = 0.

Comment: in your example 2 (with `starCaptions`) the value show in label its correct (star 1 with value = 0) but in server side its save 3.75... i need overwrite this value in server side..